# SVG text is being truncated

Tags: javascript, svg, text

I'm trying to include text in an SVG using the `<text>` element, but some reason when I do, it cuts the end off. I'm using moJS to do this. I tried adding the `overflow: visible` and still no luck. Below is the output:

```js
class TaskText extends mojs.CustomShape {
  getShape() {
    return '<text x=0 y=35 font-size="10"><tspan style="font-weight: bold; overflow: visible">Commit changes to GitHub </tspan></text>';
  }
}

mojs.addShape('tasktext', TaskText);

const text = new mojs.Shape({
  shape: 'tasktext',
  radius: 300,
  x: -30,
  scale: 0.4,
  fill: 'black',
  isShowStart: true,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mojs/latest/mo.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>Custom</title>
</head>
<body>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mojs/latest/mo.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can fix the look by manually increasing the width of the `<div>` that the SVG is nested on but I can't think of a way to target it. Is there a way to do this in SVG/JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Your text is running off the right edge of the `<svg>` element.  As I understand it, mojs,is supposed to automatically adjust the size of the SVG to accommodate the shapes you add. But it is not doing it here.  I don't know why.  You might have better luck filing an issue on the [mojs bug tracker](https://github.com/legomushroom/mojs/issues).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Ah yes, that's correct. I actually hadn't thought about that option so I'll look into it. Thanks!